# java jface passing parameters into wizard

Tags: java, parameter-passing, jface

Before I go on thanks for the earlier help.

What I would like to try now is to pass an existing parameter into a jface wizard.
I don't know if this is possible.
If any has done it, could you offer some advice.

The reason is that there is a parameter that I need to use in the new wizard.

Thanks in advance Keith

Comment: why not just creating a local variable with a setter?

Comment: I though about that, but I am trying to do is save it into list or a file. But if I don't want to get swapped with what I call static object, objects that are created once in a program